# delete object property with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i'm working on a project with angularjs.the goal of my project is to make a dynamic json generator with angular.i made a first version it works.But,there is a litlle problem with my app.when the user enters something ,the input is automatically pushed to my object with <> as key.and when the user changed his mind and clears the input form ,the key stays even if the form is empty .So, is anybody has an idea of how can i solve this problem?

this is my html :

```html
 <div  ng-controller="ctrl"  >
    
 <form>GivenName:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.givenName" ng-change='change()'/>
        <br/>FamilyName:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.familyName" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>Gender:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.gender" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>Nationality:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.nationality" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>WorksFor:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.worksFor" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>JobTitle:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.jobTitle" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>Url:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.url" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>Image:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.image" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>
    </form>
     <h1>Your JSON</h1>

    <pre>{{output | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

and my angular file:

```js
angular.module("watch", [])

.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.output = {
            "@context": {
            "schema": "http://schema.org/"
   },
           "@graph": [{
            "@id": "person",
   "@type": "schema:Person",
   }
   ]
 
    }


    $scope.person = {};
   
     function changeKeyValue() {

        for (var key in $scope.person) {
            if ($scope.person.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                $scope.output["@graph"][0]["schema:" + key] = $scope.person[key];
            }
   else if 
   
        }
    }

    $scope.change = function () {
        changeKeyValue();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an if statement in your changeKeyValue function that checks if the property value is empty, and if so then delete the key

```
if(!$scope.person[key].length){
    delete $scope.output["@graph"][0]["schema:" + key];
} else {
    $scope.output["@graph"][0]["schema:" + key] = $scope.person[key];
}
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module("watch", [])

.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.output = {
        "@context": {
            "schema": "http://schema.org/"
        },
        "@graph": [{
            "@id": "person",
   "@type": "schema:Person",
     }] 
    };

    $scope.person = {};
   
 function changeKeyValue() {

        for (var key in $scope.person) {
            if ($scope.person.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if(!$scope.person[key].length){
                   delete $scope.output["@graph"][0]["schema:" + key];
                } else {
                   $scope.output["@graph"][0]["schema:" + key] = $scope.person[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.change = function () {
        changeKeyValue();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="watch" ng-controller="ctrl"  >
    
 <form>GivenName:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.givenName" ng-change='change()'/>
        <br/>FamilyName:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.familyName" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>Gender:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.gender" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>Nationality:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.nationality" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>WorksFor:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.worksFor" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>JobTitle:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.jobTitle" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>Url:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.url" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>Image:
        <input type="text" ng-model="person.image" ng-change='change()' />
        <br/>
    </form>
     <h1>Your JSON</h1>

    <pre>{{output | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `delete` operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Your `changeKeyValue` function should look like this:

```js
function changeKeyValue() {
    for (var key in $scope.person) {
        if ($scope.person.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if($scope.person[key]) {
                $scope.output["@graph"][0]["schema:" + key] = $scope.person[key];
            }
            else {
                delete $scope.output["@graph"][0]["schema:" + key]
            }
        }   
    }
}
```